# Force strings in array to unique values without changing order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a small list containing string values I don't control. They can all be unique, all the same, whatever.
I need them to be unique and I have to preserve order, so I will add a numeric suffix to each duplicate as follows:

---

- input:
  ['same','same','same,'diff','another','another','another']
- output:
  ['same-1','same-2', 'same-3','diff','another-1,'another-2','another-3']

---

I looked at map/reduce and it seems that is about removing duplicates. My array is only up to 16 values long, but who know? Maybe I will have this issue with a much longer array.

Comment: Do you want to add the suffix to everything or just the duplicates? What if one of the unique entries was 'foo-1'?

Comment: `['same','same','same','diff','another','another','another'].map((a,b,c)=>(c.lastIndexOf(a)==b && c.indexOf(a)==b)?a:(a+"-"+c.slice(0,b+1).filter(/./.test, RegExp(a)).length ))`

Comment: suffix on duplicates only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution with [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and temporary object `this`.

```js
var data = ['same', 'same', 'same', 'diff', 'another', 'another', 'another'],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        return this[a].c === 1 ? a : a + '-' + ++this[a].i;
    }, data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = r[a] || { c: 0, i: 0 };
        r[a].c++;
        return r;
    }, {}));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A version with better performance:

```js
var data = ['same', 'same', 'same', 'diff', 'another', 'another', 'another'],
    result = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a] = o[a] || { c: 0, i: 0 };
            o[a].c++;
        });
        return array.map(function (a) {
            return o[a].c === 1 ? a : a + '-' + ++o[a].i;
        });
    }(data);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A single loop solution heavily inspired from [Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36044914/1447675)

```js
var data = ['same', 'same', 'same', 'diff', 'another', 'another', 'another'];

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (!this[a]) {
        this[a] = { i: i, c: 0 };
        return;
    }
    if (!this[a].c) {
        aa[this[a].i] += '-' + ++this[a].c;
    }   
    aa[i] += '-' + ++this[a].c;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Performance report: https://jsfiddle.net/2yhh0Lcq/   Also note that, the single loop approach reinitialize an array everytime inside the loop. That is actually not necessary in real code.

Comment: Result is typeof Object. I need Array.

Comment: @davidjmcclelland Array is an object.

Comment: can anyone tell me what a, i, c and r stand for?

Comment: `a` is an item of the array, `i` is the index, `c` is for count and `r` is the return value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (but not very fast) way:

```
['same','same','same','diff','another','another','another'].map(function(a,b,c){

  if(c.lastIndexOf(a)==b && c.indexOf(a)==b) return a; //only one, return bare
  return a+"-"+c.slice(0,b+1).filter(function(x){return a===x; }).length; //dupe, return with remaining dupe count

});

//==  ["same-1", "same-2", "same-3", "diff", "another-1", "another-2", "another-3"]
```

Comment: Internal algorithm of `indexOf`,`lastIndexOf`,`slice` and `filter` will expose that everything uses an iteration. So your code iterates four different times per iteration of outer loop, that is a map.

Answer (score 0):

A single loop approach,

```js
var x = ['same', 'same', 'same', 'diff', 'another', 'another', 'another'],dupes = {};
    
x.forEach(function(itm, i) {
 if (!dupes[itm]) {
  dupes[itm] = { cnt: 1, index: i };
 } else {
  if (dupes[itm].index !== undefined) {
    x[dupes[itm].index] += "-1";
    delete dupes[itm].index;
    dupes[itm].cnt += 1;
  }
  x[i] = x[i] + "-" + dupes[itm].cnt;
  dupes[itm].cnt += 1;
 }
});
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```